# How to associate a method with this button?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, selector, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation bar button that displays both image and text. This is the code:

```
UIImage *saveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];

UIButton *saveButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[saveButton setBackgroundImage:saveImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

saveButton.frame = (CGRect) {
    .size.width = 100,
    .size.height = 30,
};

UIBarButtonItem *barButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:saveButton];

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButton animated:YES];
```

I tried this

```
[barButton setAction:@selector(saveArray)];
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that you must specify target as well. You can set action/target to the UIButton object itself:

```
[saveButton addTarget:target action:@selector(saveArray) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I've tried to set target/action to the UIBarButtonItem directly but it seems not to work in case of UIButton for custom view for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set the target? If the desired method belongs to the same class, you could do:

```
[barButton setTarget:self];
```

That said, `action` and `target` are both properties (new to Obj-C 2.0), consider using the dot notation:

```
barButton.action = @selector(saveArray:)
barButton.target = self;
```